# Is there a way to create one panel page for multiple i.e 7,8 view displays

Tags: views, panels, chaos-tool-suite

A view has 7-8 displays … all of them are pages. I want them to layout (i.e the page) when any of the 7 pages is visited the view content should come up in the left pane of a panel i.e col-sm-8(bootstrap class) while the right col-sm-4 should be reserved for sidebar purpose.

There are several ways to do it … what would you suggest ? Should I create a panel page for each of the view display or there is a way to create one panel page for all ? i.e targeting there URL paths

- /news
- /most-read
- ... etc

Comment: Why don't you write a template override for that view and add the bootstrap classes into the template?

Comment: from panel's UI I want to add several other stuff too it ... 
i.e on left col-sm-8 there will be current views content while on the right col-sm-4 there will be search, another view, some other content ... etc